# How to get cursor result count using the MongoDB PHP extension

Tags: php, mongodb, php-mongodb

The [`mongo`](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mongo.php) PHP extension is deprecated in favour of the [`mongodb`](http://php.net/manual/en/set.mongodb.php) extension. This extension is used together with the [`mongo-php-library`](http://mongodb.github.io/mongo-php-library/).

In the old extension one could get the result count from the cursor using [MongoCursor::count()](http://php.net/manual/en/mongocursor.count.php). However, the new cursor [MongoDB\Driver\Cursor](http://php.net/manual/en/class.mongodb-driver-cursor.php) has no such method. What is the new way of getting the number of results from after performing a query against MongoDB?

Comment: Is there a way to get the count result without having to get all the results from the Mongo server? All I need is the count.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I use this code.

```
$query = ["hello" => "world"];
$command = new MongoDB\Driver\Command(["count" => "collection", "query" => $query]);
try {
    $result = $mongo->executeCommand("mydb", $command);
    $res = current($result->toArray());
    $count = $res->n;
    echo $count;
} catch (MongoDB\Driver\Exception\Exception $e) {
    echo $e->getMessage(), "\n";
}
```

Comment: Is this pulling all the data along with the query... or just counting the responses?   My documents are large and I'm trying to avoid the entire set of documents from having to come across the wire just to count them.

Comment: @lowcrawler only returns a number, in fact this code works the same as    db.runCommand( { count: 'collection' } ) and return { "n" : 26, "ok" : 1 }.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it like this

```
Model::count(array($whereClause));
```

The `$whereClause` would be your search criteria basically.

Otherwise, if your query returns an array, you could do

```
$data = Model::find(array($whereClause));
$total = count($data);
```

Comment: But that means that when I want to get the actual results as well, I have to perform two queries.

Comment: @ChinLeung what's "Model::"?

Comment: @Drumnbass It's the name of the class.