# PHP Mongodb Count Result

Tags: php, mongodb, php-mongodb

I'm performing a simple request to my MongoDB in php. It looks like this:

```
$result = $this->myMongoClient->myCollection->find([
    'param_1' => $param_1,
    'param_2' => $param_2,
]);
```

This returns a `MongoDB\Driver\Cursor` object. I need the count of returned entrys from the database.

I've googeld a while and found this. But with this function dose not exists on the object returend by MongoDB (`Call to undefined method MongoDB\Driver\Cursor::count()`)

```
$result->count()
```

Which is the commun way to count the number of results?

Answer (score 1):

I have found a solution, but don't know if it is recommendable or not.

```
count($result->toArray());
```

Comment: That's going to pull all of the data for the result set out of the database instead of just executing a count on the data in the DB.

Comment: Is there an alternative?

Comment: Some alternatives here:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36726069/how-to-get-cursor-result-count-using-the-mongodb-php-extension

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if you are using the `MongoDB PHP Library`, but if you are you can just use the following

```
$result = $this->myMongoClient->myCollection->countDocuments($where);
```

https://docs.mongodb.com/php-library/master/reference/method/MongoDBCollection-countDocuments/index.html

Comment: Yes i'm using the offical php library. With this solution I have to send two requests to the database one to get the documents and one to count them. Am I right?

Comment: Yes, this method would require you to make 2 separate calls to the database if you wanted both a document count and the documents themselves.